# A 2.4ghz simple colpitts oscillator circuit

Tags: electromagnetic

Can someone please show me how to make a 2.4ghz circuit that produces a sinewave. Maybe a simple colpitt oscillator. Componants sizes etc

Comment: I would personally recommend a PLL chip with a decent TCXO reference, if you want to have any reasonable (ppm) accuracy.

Comment: What have YOU found sofar ? There is plenty information available but you have to look for it. I suggest reading a textbook about RF design and oscillators and start from there.

Comment: Also, start with a 10 MHz oscillator, when you have that working a  100 MHz oscillator, then 1 GHz and then 2.4 GHz (if you make it that far hehe).

Comment: This document might help: http://www.skyworksinc.com/uploads/documents/200320A.pdf

Comment: The asker is clearly pretty clueless. Pick up a book on RF design. I personally like RF Circuit Design by Bowick. SE is not a substitute for fundamental knowledge - it can only help you if you already have it.

Comment: I have made a 1mhz colpitt oscillator. Now I need to make a 2.4ghz colpitt oscillator. Can I produce one with different componants.

Comment: @user92594 as the answer says a Colpitts isn't practical for that frequency and you'll also need a proper PCB. If this is just for a one-off experiment you can buy built boards for $10 on e-bay just search for "2.4GHz oscillator".

Comment: I've tried typing that on ebay for built boards there arnt any. Can u recommend a site where I can purchase one please.

Answer (score 4):

2.4 Ghz is just too fast to work well in a discrete implementation. In a Colpitts circuit, the oscillator frequency is equal to the resonant frequency of the LC tank circuit, ie f=1/(2*pi*sqrt(LC). This means that even with the smallest available capacitor (1 pf), you would need an approximately 4nH inductor. This would be about the inductance of a 4mm length of wire- and that's before parasitic capacitances and inductances come into play. You'll probably need to look at an integrated solution like the MAX2753.